# Этимология наречия «незнамо»

Tags: этимология, словообразование

Как произошло слово *незнамо*? Есть ли слова с похожей словообразовательной моделью?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Знамо и незнамо действительно имеют интересную этимологию, потому что первое, что приходит в голову, это происхождение от современного литературного причастия знаемо и незнаемо, так сказать,  диалектный и просторечный вариант = известно (неизвестно), ясно (неясно)

Но словарь РЯ XI-XVII говорит: знамо, нареч. от устаревшего прилагательного знамый «известный, знакомый» (1509 г.).
https://sovereign_patrimony.academic.ru/521

Многие наречия в р.я. возникли на базе кратких прилагательных ср.р. ед.ч. И.-В.п. Подобные формы часто выступали в несогласованном отношении с субъектом высказывания: …въ лодье гребьци гребуть невидимо, токмо весла видhти… (Лаврентьевская летопись); …исповhдающе вьсе како различьно святhи сеи пакости дhяху… (Успенский сборник). Не согласуясь с именем, эти формы становятся несогласованными определениями к глаголу, т.е. наречием.

Римма привела в пример семо и овамо -это  более древние наречия, местоимённые, они первообразны.

В большинстве своем они образовались от падежных форм древних склоняемых слов с распространителем *d (кдhе, куда, куду). Основная функция таких слов была указательной. Происхождение подобных наречий можно выяснить лишь путем специального этимологического анализа. Вот список таких наречий, встречающихся в памятниках древнерусского языка: куда – куды , туда – туды, сюда – сюды, вьсюду – вьсюдh; къдh (где), къгда (когда), тъгда (тогда); иногда, овогда (иногда), вьсегда, вьсьдh (везде), съдhсь; семо, тамо, камо (куда), како (как), тако (так), семо, тамо, овамо (туда), колико (как много, сколько), колижьды – колижьдо (сколь часто), коли (когда). На базе многих перечисленных первообразных наречий возникли приставочные образования: отътудh – оттуда, отсюда, докуда, дотуда, отовсюду, повсюду, обоюду, обоюдh (с обеих сторон); доколе, никако, никамо, никогда, нигде, никуда и др.

Эта группа наречий со временем сокращалась, многие наречия вышли из употребления (камо, овамо, овогда и др.).

Answer (score 2):

Не — отрицательная частица, знамый — известный (отмечено в старых словарях, например, Преображенского).

Словообразование с суффиксом **-мо** раньше было широко распространено. Другие примеры подобного словообразования: вестимо, письмо, дерьмо, бельмо. Последние три примера взяты из этимологического словаря Шапошникова А.К.

Upd. В примерах смешаны разные типы словообразования с **-мо**, см. комментарии.

Comment: *Вестимо*, в отличие от *письмо, дерьмо* и т. п., не существительное, так что вы спутали суффиксы. Точнее было бы указание на наречное значение суффикса *-мо* в словах типа *сидьмо*. Тем не менее указание на прилагательное *знамый* действительно полезно. Спасибо.

Comment: Да, согласен, с суффиксами намешал лишнего.

Answer (score 2):

**Вид/и/мо, не/вид/и/мо** — от прил. видимый, из гл. видеть, от праслав. *viděti;
**терп/и/мо, не/с/терп/и/мо** — от прил. терпимый, нетерпимый;
**зримо, незримо** — от зримо (зримый), от гл. зреть, от др.-русск. зьрѣти, зьрю.

Возможно: касаемо; ведомо, неведомо; семо и овамо.

**знамо, незнамо** [не + знамо] — от *ЗНать, знаю, знаешь; знать, Р. знáти собир. знатные люди; знатный, діал. знáмый извѣстный («знамо дѣло»)...*

[**А. Г. Преображенский. Этимологический словарь русского языка. 1910**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=YqD6AgAAQBAJ&pg=PA253&dq=%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F%20znati&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiI8J6ou8TZAhWNh7QKHYtUBc8Q6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F%20znati&f=false)